# SQL Stored Procedure WHILE loop BEGIN END then do something

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I can't figure out why my Select statement won't run after my WHILE EXISTS() loop.

This code is written within a stored procedure and runs perfectly fine, expect it won't return the select statement at the end, I just get the Command(s) completed successfully.

If I put the select statement before end I get stuck in an endless loop....

any ideas please

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #staging AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK))
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

       /*Do Stuff*/

        SELECT TOP 1
        @Index = FHD.[index]            
        FROM #staging AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK)


        COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

       /*Do Stuff*/


    END CATCH

    DELETE FHD
    FROM #staging AS FHD
    WHERE FHD.[index] = @Index

END

Select * from #table
```

Comment: Could it be that table #staging never becomes empty?

Comment: Maybe you have `SET XACT_ABORT ON` which won't continue to run instructions after a failure.

Comment: I've updated my code, I'm very sure my staging becomes empty otherwise i would get stuck in an endless loop

Comment: I would put `print` statements everywhere to see which branches the code is going through and how many times. As it stands the only reason I can think of is that you are getting an error in the rest of your code which is causing the transaction to rollback.

Comment: the print shows all lines in staging execute.... hmmm

Comment: In that case the code you have posted doesn't accurately reflect the problem. You need to post the minimal version of code which reproduces the error - so create a temp table, put some data in, run the code and have the error produced. Otherwise its just a guessing game. (And you'll probably solve the issue at the same time).

Comment: Maybe #table is empty.  Either way, your repro is not complete.

Comment: Let's see. You're trying to find some sort of key in a table using nolock hint. Then you try to delete those rows matching that ID. That hint Makes no sense. You put try/catch around the select/do something block but not the delete statement. Makes no sense. Your catch block eats the error so you have no idea if that portion of the logic works. Again - makes no sense. Just use a cursor since that is what your over-complicated logic is simulating.